# How to make PhpStorm not auto-expand methods in a class

Tags: phpstorm

Class methods are exposed in the file system, they take up a lot of space and are not needed.

How to make them not show?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open "Project View" panel options (right click on the panel header or click on the gear/cog icon)
2. Ensure that "Tree Appearance | Show Members" is unchecked/disabled.

   [image]

---

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#title_bar_context_menu

> **Show Members**
>
> If this option is on, the files in the tree that contain classes turn into nodes. When such node is unfolded, the contained classes with their fields, methods, and other members of the selected item are shown.
>
> [image]